# Custom Font in Text View/Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, objective-c, text, interface-builder, textview

I hope this is a really simple question, but it's stumped me. Basically, I have a huge amount of text that I'm using the text view for. For the most part, it's just the system font. However, I would like to format "headers" every few paragraphs in the large chunk of text with a custom font (that I've added to my project) and background color.  How do I target small pieces of text within the text view?

If it were just a small piece of text, I would just add a label and do it with code,  but since this a huge piece of text, what's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I forgot to mention this text is completely static and non-editable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load a large amount of static text with formatting, I suggest you save it as a html file and load it into UIWebView.

Comment: thanks, I thinking it would be something like this. I will try it.

Comment: just came back to say this was a very good solution, thanks again